# cutting simmetrically python dictionary with respect to a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a lot of python dictionaries in which the keys are  progressive integer numbers and the values are some int. At a certain point there is always a zero in the keys, and I need to cut this dictionaries in a simmetric way with respect to this zero (like I need from the keys -100 to the +100). It seems stupid but I cannot think to a way to do this. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Just loop over your dictionary and create a copy that only includes the keys you want.

Comment: can you show some data/ code that you have ?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved printing everything in a file and putting an if condition when I acquired again! Maybe is not the best but it works, thanks anyway!